# I have commented both k-slide() and k-change() events descriptions, but still when I drag-drop the slider, its removing part of my URL

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-slider

[Below is the link. While I drag drop slider with commented event body, still "#!#35157" of my link vanished. I suspect it may be the routing issue but how sliders are firing change or slide events though everything are commented? It works fine when I use click to sliders track line to change value.](http://hostname/branch/WebHtml.Client/#!#35157)

Comment: Angular wrapped **Kendo Sliders**

Comment: Solved! was a routing issue.